# How to restore deleted table from django migrations?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I've deleted both table and 0001_initial.py migration file from a model. I didn`t think I will need this model anymore, but now I do need it.

The problem is that python manage.py makemigrations doesn't create a table with the name of deleted table and therefore my migrations are only displayed in migrations files. But they don`t affect database.

How can I create or restore that table again or should I delete the whole database and restore everything afterwards?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hmmm. Create model again and run `makemigrations`. Also never delete files of applied migrations. I see 0 reasons to do so

Answer (score -1):

It can sound stupid but did you check bin in your machine?